# Restricting/limiting number of times a model.foreignkey choice can be chosen in python django (fantasy sports website)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd5NC.png)I am in the process of making a fantasy sports website. The django out-of-the-box User equals a team owner. On my blog/models.py file, I created a class of `Player` (aka an NBA player) with a foreignkey field of `player_owner` pointing back to `User`:

```
# blog/models.py
class Player(models.Model):
    player_full = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    player_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_player.jpg', upload_to='player_pics')
    player_unit_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                                                            MaxValueValidator(1)])
```

As you can see, I also have a field on the Player class called `player_unit_value` set permanently to 1. This, i think, will come into play with my question. I have a lot of the website set up: Free Agents Page, Team Dashboard, Player Profile, financials etc all built out with form validation to ensure players are "signed" and "dropped" by the authorized signed-in `User` (aka team owner).

```
# blog/views.py
class PlayersUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView, Player):
    model = Player
    fields = []
    template_name = 'blog/player_form.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'guys'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.player_owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thus, when you click "add player" on my site, that player's `player_owner` field is updated from "None" to the `User`. and the "Drop Player" button does the reverse.

**So here is my question:** How can I create a logic that limits the number of times a `User` (aka owner) can be selected as the `player_owner` to 15? Ideally, I'd like there to be some sort of form validation that --when initiated by a `User` who already has 15 players-- shows an invalid warning saying "Sorry, you already have your max number of players on your roster"

Here is another part that might be of use: I created a field on my Users/models.py Profile class called `players_owned`:

```
# users/models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    players_owned = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,
                                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                                             MaxValueValidator(15)]
                                                 )
```

I suspect there may be a way to += 1 to the User's `players_owned` field every time a `Player` is added to the User's team (aka every time the Player.player_owner field is updated from None to a `User` (aka Owner). But these two classes are on different model files.

I'm new to python and django, so my apologies in advance if this is a little nuts.

---

Updated code:

## blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Sum, Q
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView)
from users.forms import ProfileUpdateForm
from .models import Post, Player

class PlayersUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView, Player):
    model = Player
    fields = []
    template_name = 'blog/player_form.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ProfileUpdateForm()
        return render(request=request, template_name=self.template_name, context={
            "form": form
    })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.user.players_owned <= 5:
                form.instance.player_owner = self.request.user
                request.user.players_owned = request.user.players_owned + 1
                request.user.save()
                return redirect("players-update")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Sorry, you already have the max number of players on your roster")
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**Questions:** Should I import model `Profile` from users/models.py? Maybe this def doesnt belong on the `PlayerUpdateView`?

## blog/models.py: *not changed*

## blog/player_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <script>
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                alert(message);
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </script>
</head>
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Adding {{ object.player_full }}</legend>
                <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.image.url }}">
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <h4>Are you sure you want to add <kbd>{{ object.player_full }}</kbd> to your team?</h4>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Add Player</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'players-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

## users/models.py

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    players_owned = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,
                                                 validators [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(15)])
```

## users/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        # when submitted creates ...user
        model = User
        # these are the fields we want on our form
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        # when submitted updates ...user
        model = User
        # these are the fields we want on our form
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image', 'players_owned']
```

Question: Should I use the `UserUpdateForm` instead?

BTW, here is the latest error I got:

```
NoReverseMatch at /players/529/update/
Reverse for 'players-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['players/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/players/529/update/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'players-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['players/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the form_valid element of your view to check against players_owned:

-----Edit

Here is the way I like to do my class based views, with get and post requests, and then you can access the request object. If this is too different from your original code, and you want to keep the `form_valid` function let me know and I can try to change it to be closer to what you have currently.

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

class PlayersUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView, Player):

```
template_name = "template_name.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = FORM_NAME()
    return render(request=request, template_name=self.template_name, context={
        "form": form
    })
def post(self, request): 
    form = FORM_NAME(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            if request.user.players_owned <= 15:
                form.instance.player_owner = self.request.user
                request.user.players_owned = request.user.players_owned + 1
                request.user.save()
                return redirect("wherever you want to go on success")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Sorry, you already have your max number of players on your roster")
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

---end of edit

and then in your template add this to display messages, which is an error in this case. If you want to display the form again, use `{{form.as_p}}`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    alert(message);
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{form.as_p}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!

PyCharm is listing `request` as an unresolved reference in views. When I try to add it in with `def form_valid(self, form):` it is not a fan of that as well. Is there somewhere else I need to put it?

Comment: PyCharm recommended I import request via django.http.request or urllib.request. So I tried with django.http.request and the error when I ran it through was ...
`AttributeError at /players/523/update/
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: ah yes sorry, I assumed by your use of 'form.instance.player_owner = self.request.user' that you already had it. I like to define it as either a post or get request. I modified my answer accordingly. If it differs to much from what you want let me know

Comment: Ok now I have a new error: `TypeError at /players/525/update/
get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

for reference, on my URLS:
`path('players/<int:pk>/', PlayersDetailView.as_view(), name='players-detail'),`

Also PyCharm is saying `def get(self, request):` is "Signature of method 'PlayersUpdateView.get()' does not match signature of base method in class 'BaseUpdateView' "

And finally `FORM_NAME` is being listed as an unresolved reference. 

I can re-post the code as it looks now if that would help. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Or actually, this is the path that includes `PlayersUpdateView`

    path('players/<int:pk>/update/', PlayersUpdateView.as_view(), name='players-update'),

not sure if that is relevant

Comment: I added `*args and **kwargs` arguments in both `post` and `get` and that moved on to the next error: `FORM_NAME' is not defined`

Comment: FORM_NAME is a placeholder, I was saying put your form name there

Comment: Oh i see, might be a problem: the `players_owned` field that I made lives on the the `Profile` model which is in the users directory. That directory also has the form I think is being used called `ProfileUpdateForm`. All of the other views, models, & html templates I am using are on my `blog` directory. Do I need to place that `players_owned` field on my actual built-in `User` model- not Profile? Is that possible? If i Import ProfileUpdateForm to my blog/views.py I am able to run it through the code if I delete all other html. But it still doesn't work. Thanks for helping with this! updating Q

Comment: your Profile class should extend the base user through a OnetoOne relationship, and I don't think you are doing this right. See this link for more info on how to do this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: The only difference I have from the link's method of extension with a profile is that my `@reciever` for create profile and save profile are found on a separate file called users/signals.py. When I tried moving them under Profile in users/models I lost my ability to register new users. on my forms file i have UserUpdateForm and ProfileUpdateForm. the players_owned field exists on the ProfileUpdateForm. Should I try and switch that? Or did you say there was another method that related a little more towards my initial code?

Comment: Follow the tutorial I linked above, because you are trying to extend the user class with your profile class, and you did it incorrectly